# Load “my blog entries” on profile pages

Tags: blocks, views

I have created the view “my blog entries” which should be displayed on a user’s profile page. In terms of displaying not all but only the currently viewed user’s blog entries I have added the *Contextual Filter* called *Content: Author uid.*

In a second step I created a block, which is only present on listed pages: “profile/*”

So now I can go to a user’s profile page (root/profile/3) and the block is enabled, the view is loaded and will load only entries from that very user.

In terms of improving SEO I used URL-Aliases to get something like this: root/profile/the-actual-user-name

For obvious reasons my view won’t work anymore. How to get it work again without the user-ID in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your contextual filter use **Provide default value, User ID From URL.** (this automatically extracts the uid from the url (page) and the uid does not need to be in the url).

[image]